Can't clone using RSA / Ed25519 / ECDSA on GitHub "Permission denied (publickey)"
RSA algorithm:

ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "esp...uin@gmail.com"

Enter file in which to save the key (/home/eljoaca/.ssh/id_rsa): ENTER
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): ENTER
Enter same passphrase again: ENTER

eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"

Agent pid 5251

ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Identity added: /home/eljoaca/.ssh/id_rsa (esp...uin@gmail.com)

cat id_rsa.pub copy. On Github add new SSH Key, Key type Authentication Key, paste, Add SSH key.

git clone ...


The authenticity of host 'github.com (20.201.28.151)' can't be established. ED25519 key fingerprint is SHA256:+DiY3wvvV6TuJJhbpZisF/zLDA0zPMSvHdkr4UvCOqU. This key is not known by any other names Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? YES
Warning: Permanently added 'github.com' (ED25519) to the list of known hosts. ERROR: You're using an RSA key with SHA-1, which is no longer allowed. Please use a newer client or a different key type. Please see https://github.blog/2021-09-01-improving-git-protocol-security-github/ for more information.
fatal: could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.

ssh -vT git@github.com

...
debug1: identity file /home/eljoaca/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
...
Hi ElJoaca! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access. debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1 Transferred: sent 3588, received 3088 bytes, in 0.6 seconds Bytes per second: sent 5836.7, received 5023.3 debug1: Exit status 1

ssh -T git@github.com

Hi ElJoaca! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
Solutions tried for RSA algorithm:

Use a different key type (Ed25519 / ECDSA).

Ed25519 algorithm:

ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "esp...uin@gmail.com"

eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"

ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_ed25519

Add the SSH public key to my account on GitHub

git clone ...


The authenticity of host 'github.com (20.201.28.151)' can't be established. ED25519 key fingerprint is SHA256:+DiY3wvvV6TuJJhbpZisF/zLDA0zPMSvHdkr4UvCOqU. This key is not known by any other names Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? YES
Warning: Permanently added 'github.com' (ED25519) to the list of known hosts. git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.

ssh -vT git@github.com

...
debug1: identity file /home/eljoaca/.ssh/id_ed25519 type 3
...
debug1: No more authentication methods to try. git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).

ssh -T git@github.com

git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
ECDSA algorithm:

Exactly the same for ECDSA, git clone ...

The authenticity of host 'github.com (20.201.28.151)' can't be established. ED25519 key fingerprint is SHA256:+DiY3wvvV6TuJJhbpZisF/zLDA0zPMSvHdkr4UvCOqU. This key is not known by any other names Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? YES
Warning: Permanently added 'github.com' (ED25519) to the list of known hosts. git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.

ssh -vT git@github.com

...
debug1: identity file /home/eljoaca/.ssh/id_ecdsa type 2
...
debug1: No more authentication methods to try. git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).

ssh -T git@github.com

git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
Solutions attempted for these last 2:

Create the config file with the following lines:
Host github.com
HostName github.com
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
IdentitiesOnly yes

Review the permissions of the directories:
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/private_key
chmod 644 ~/.ssh/public_key
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/config


More information

OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.7, OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022

I can clone a repository using the RSA algorithm from GitLab


